# Getting "Syntax Error: invalid or unexpected token" in Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, puppeteer, cheerio

I'm trying to run a script using Puppeteer framework. (I'm a relative newbie to software). Every time I try to run, I get the error below. I'm sure nothing is wrong with the code as it worked fine an a different machine earlier. This error is noted right as main.js makes the (only) function call.

```
SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at new Script (vm.js:80:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:274:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:326:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:664:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:754:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
```

```
var puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
var $ = require('cheerio');
const url = 'https://www.reddit.com/controversial/';
​
puppeteer
  .launch()
  .then(function(browser) {
    return browser.newPage();
  })
  .then(function(page) {
    return page.goto(url).then(function() {
      return page.content();
    });
  })
  .then(function(html) {
    $('h2', html).each(function() {
        console.log($(this).text());
        console.log('\r\n');
    });
    })
  .catch(function(err) {
    //handle error
  });
```

I've uninstalled, cleaned, reinstalled Node.js as per this link ([How do I completely uninstall Node.js, and reinstall from beginning (Mac OS X)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177954/how-do-i-completely-uninstall-node-js-and-reinstall-from-beginning-mac-os-x))

Comment: What's your Node version (`node -v`)? And can you post some of your code? There may be syntax that only works in newer Node versions.

Comment: What version of Puppeteer are you using? there was a bug fix for a similar error: https://github.com/aslushnikov/puppeteer/commit/510ecbad22e5f3d92ceb0291f263c49169f795e0

Comment: my version of node is 10.15.3

Comment: Cool, that version of Node is recent, so that's probably not the problem. To find your version of puppeteer, try `cat package.json` from the project root. If it doesn't appear in there, try `grep version node_modules/puppeteer/package.json`

Comment: my version of puppeteer is 1.14.0

Comment: That version of puppeteer is also very recent, so the bug alfasin found (good find!) probably isn't the issue. Can you post any of your code?

Comment: yes, just posted code

Comment: I added a followup as an answer -- this solution fixed it on both my Mac and Linux.

Answer (score 8):

This isn't actually related to puppeteer at all. On line 4, you have a [zero width space](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200B/index.htm) character, which doesn't look like anything, but makes your Node program invalid. This sometimes shows up if you're copying a line from a site or some other source.

If you delete that line and insert a blank new line, you should be fine. I tested by copying out your code, installing the dependencies, and running it. Depending on your editor, you should be able to show unexpected unicode characters like this.

Comment: wow, thank you. that fixed it! how did you spot that? i'd never come across that before

Comment: I have my editor (Vim) set to show unicode characters, using [this Vim plugin](https://github.com/vim-utils/vim-troll-stopper), so as soon as I copied your code into Vim it showed up. There's probably a plugin or config to get that to work for your editor, depending on what you use. I added that to my Vim config because I work with a lot of devs who use Windows, so it's sometimes an issue.